# How can I generate a 10-day report every day using ISA Server 2006?

Tags: reporting, isa-server

We're using ISA Server 2006 (Version 5.0.5723.514)

Our ISP imposes a 10GB usage limit per 10 day cycle.  What I would like to do is generate a report automatically on a daily basis, showing our usage for the previous 10 days.  It would also be nice to send out a notification should the total usage exceed 10GB.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I set it up?